# Why are there pending TXs with high gas prices?

Tags: gas, testnets, gas-price, pending-transactions, rinkeby

[Rinkeby has pending transactions](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/txsPending), some of which have gas prices of 100+ gwei and have been pending for over half an hour. Why is that? Are sending too little gas?

Comment: Rinkeby is a test network, so there's no economy factor involved to choose higher priced over regular transactions. Another possibility can be if the account doesn't have enough funds to pay for the execution. Or the gas limit is above the limit of the network.